# Technical question on perimeter of level sets

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

Sorry for asking such a basic question, but this is not my area of expertise.

In my work I'm using the coarea formula: for $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded, and $u : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ Lipschitz,

$\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u| = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathcal{H}_{n-1}(u^{-1}(t))dt$.

I can calculate the LHS and want to use this to reason about the RHS.

**Question:** Is it true that there is a "standard definition" of surface area such that for almost all $t$, the set $L_t = \{x \in \Omega : u(x) \geq t\}$ is "nice enough" that SurfaceArea$(L_t) = \mathcal{H}_{n-1}(u^{-1}(t))$?  And is there a reasonable reference for this?

If it makes a difference, my $u$ is actually defined on the torus $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$, which may make things cleaner.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't $L_t$ equal to $\{u=t\}$ rather than $\{u\geq t\}$ ?

Comment: What kind of regularity do you have on $u$?

Comment: @Thomas Richard: no, intuitively one would expect that the boundary of `$\{u \geq t\}$` would be `$\{u = t\}$`.

@Benoit Kloekcner: well... suppose it's merely Lipschitz -- am I out of luck?  

Comment: @Benoit Kloekcner: Actually, in my application with a little work I can make $u$ piecewise-affine, in which case everything is completely fine.  However, I would prefer if I could just leave it Lipschitz and cite something, rather than throw in an extra approximation argument.

Comment: I do not have an answer, but this seems plausible for Lipschitz functions. You could have a look in Federer's book or on functional inequalities where this kind of thing are used (sample keywords: Faber-Krahn, Schwarz symmetrization).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes. You can take as surface area of a set the (total) variation of its characteristic function. This is the "standard definition" of [perimeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caccioppoli_set#Caccioppoli_definition) for general measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. See, for example, [this book](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=AUCN&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=ambrosio&s5=fusco&s6=pallara&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=1857292), in particular Definition 3.35 and Theorem 3.40.

Comment: (The link above, http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1857292, is to the review of **Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems**, by Ambrosio, Fusco, and Pallara.)


Comment: Excellent reference, thanks bezirsk!